# Ignore a path entry with bash tab-completion

Tags: bash, path, autocomplete, tab-completion

I have two commands, `foo` and `foo-bar`, where `foo` is a symlink to `foo-bar`. I want to be able to type `f`+TAB (pretend these are the only two commands on the path that begin with `f`) and have one of them be completed (meaning the full name **and** the space after).

What ends up happening though is that it completes to just `foo` (no space) because of `foo-bar`. It's obviously not much work to then just hit the space bar, but this interrupts my flow.

Some additional details:

- `foo` and `foo-bar` are in the same directory.
- Deleting/moving `foo` isn't an option (I've hidden some details).

Is there a way to ignore a specific path entry?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use FIGNORE, although it has some strange properties.

FIGNORE requires a proper suffix.  So to ignore foo-bar, any of these will work:

```
FIGNORE=bar
FIGNORE=-bar
FIGNORE=r
FIGNORE=oo-bar
```

The import thing is **not** to try `FIGNORE=foo-bar` since it's not a proper suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
FIGNORE=foo-bar
```

Comment: This almost works, but as noted in the accepted solution, FIGNORE requires a proper suffix.

Comment: @Ed: Sorry, I misread your question, I was setting it to ignore foo instead of foo-bar. However, `FIGNORE=foo-bar` works for me.

Comment: Strange, not sure why `FIGNORE=foo-bar` works for you (doesn't for me). `FIGNORE=oo-bar` does work for me though.

Comment: @Ed: I tried it on both Cygwyn with Bash 3.2.49(23)-release and Ubuntu with 4.0.33(1)-release. What version is yours?

Comment: I tested on bash 3.2.39(1)-release (openSUSE 11.1) and bash 3.2.48(1)-release (OS X 10.6) and bash 4.0.35(1)-release (Fedora Core 12).  In all those versions, it only works when I use proper suffix.  Have no idea why you are seeing something different.

Comment: I tested on bash 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).