# How do I get bash on OS X Lion to ignore .DS_Store files during tab completion?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line

I have lots of directories with a single file in them.  The presence of .DS_Store files makes filename completion a little awkward.  How do I tell bash to ignore .DS_Store files when I hit tab?

Comment: This is already answered on stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225976/ignore-a-path-entry-with-bash-tab-completion

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A better method is to also exclude the other things that might already be in FIGNORE using

`export FIGNORE="$FIGNORE:DS_Store"`

Comment: minor, but i'd stick it in quotes: ```export FIGNORE="$FIGNORE:.DS_Store"``` .

a minor bummer with this is that it even if .DS_Store is the only file which matches what you've typed so far, it won't complete.  so for example ```rm ./.DS_<TAB>``` will yield no auto-complete choices.

Answer (score 26):

Add this line to your `.bash_profile` file:

```
export FIGNORE=DS_Store
```