# Bash, tab completion, and an ignore list

Tags: macos, bash

I use bash often on Mac OS X, as you are probably aware, the window parameters such as position, size, etc, are stored in an invisible to the user, file called .DS_Store.  This of course is visible to users of any shell or command line.

I use the built in Terminal.app and the stock bash that it comes with:

```
$uname -a
Darwin boo.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I was going to paste the bash version in here, but a bash -v output all my settings and I noticed a trailing 'history -a' that I hope someone can tell me what that is all about:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"
export HISTIGNORE="&:ls:[bf]g:exit"
```

The above I believe has been that way for years.  I don't remember exactly what it does, but I use control-r often and history search through it.  Any ideas why it would all of a sudden be echoing out the history -a command?

My main issue, is tab completion.  I am ok with how it works on bash under OS X, with one exception. The .DS_Store files seem to get in my way more often than I want them to.  I can hit tab, and there is technically only one dot file I want to complete, so either a single tab will do it, or a dot character then a tab.  But no, I can't do that, because there is actually two files, there is a .DS_Store file, and while I may have masked it from my listing of the `ls` command, it is still there.

Is there a way to exclude certain files from tab completion and have them ignored?

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with programming. [unix.se] is probably the best place to ask; [apple.se] could also work. And I'm not sure what you are asking, either. It seems that you should be splitting this up into more than one question.

Comment: 'Tis curious that you find `.DS_Store` files show up too often.  I've not experienced that problem — but I guess that means I do things differently from you (and that doesn't make either of us right or wrong).  Have you looked at [How do I get bash on OS X Lion to ignore .DS_Store files during tab completion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058273/how-do-i-get-bash-on-os-x-lion-to-ignore-ds-store-files-during-tab-completion)  What is missing from it?  Treat the reference to Lion as tangential to the issue.  Actually, on second thoughts, I think it is simple and complete.

Comment: Well, I will be darned, thanks for that link, I did search but was not able to find it, from the title, it looks like what I am looking for. My other question is about the PROMPT_COMMAND and how it works on OS X specifically, as it is a little different i believe; some settings can be set in the terminal prefs, so I never know which take precedent, if any at all.  Thx for the link!